# Best way to implement pullToRefresh on Ionic App

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, pull-to-refresh

I am using ion-refresher directive to implement pull to refresh in my App. So far I am able to implement it on invidicual controllers and corresponding HTMLs

I need to implement it for all my screens. Each if  my screens have a different set of promise functions that need to be called. I want to avoid writing the same code for each screen.

Is there a way to attach the doRefresh to the root scope and Have the directive implemented such that I can avoid repetition and spamming in my code.

Any suggestions would be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For having ion-refresher in every page of your application and to have the refresh function at one place you need to write the function in **app.js** file something like:

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, $http) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }

    $rootScope.doRefresh = function(page) {
      $http.get('PATH OF API')
       .success(function(newItems) {
          console.log("success "+page);
       })
       .finally(function() {
         // Stop the ion-refresher from spinning
         $rootScope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
       });
    };

  });
})
```

After that say for example you have 3 pages in your application called 1) Dashboard 2) Chats 3) Account then you need to write below mentioned directive in each template file :

```
<ion-refresher
    pulling-text="Pull to refresh..."
    on-refresh="doRefresh('dash')">
  </ion-refresher>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item class="item-remove-animate item-avatar item-icon-right" ng-repeat="chat in chats" type="item-text-wrap" href="#/tab/chats/{{chat.id}}">
      <img ng-src="{{chat.face}}">
      <h2>{{chat.name}}</h2>
      <p>{{chat.lastText}}</p>
      <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>

      <ion-option-button class="button-assertive" ng-click="remove(chat)">
        Delete
      </ion-option-button>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

here **doRefresh('dash')** is the function with argument which has the current screen name ( Here it dash is for Dashboard ). Similarly for other pages as well.

Now inside of dorefresh() function in app.js file you can put condition based on passed argument in function and call according promise function.

Hope you find the correct answer by this.

Comment: Thanks.. this helps!